# Pictures not attached in file

Tags: python, excel-2010, image

I am using python win32 to drive excel 2010. I want to insert pictures into certain cells

```
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import constants as constants

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True

wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
ws.Name = 'PicDemo' ## rename worksheet

## select the active sheet
excel.Sheets('PicDemo').Select()
ws = excel.ActiveSheet
ws.Cells(9,9).Select()

## insert a png pic into this cell
ws.Pictures().Insert(pic file path)
```

I can see the pictures inserted on my PC, but when I send the excel to my friend, they couldn't see the picture but red cross with 'invalid link'.

I search the web and a lot of people complained about this glitch in excel 2010. I just want the pics saved absolutely without any dependent linking.

Is there a python win32 workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft changed the behavior in Excel 2010 and 2013. Try this:

```
xlApp = win32.Dispatch(r'Excel.Application')
xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(sheet_name)
rng = xlSheet.Range("B2:F8")
height = rng.Offset(rng.Rows.Count, 0).Top - rng.Top
width = rng.Offset(0, rng.Columns.Count).Left - rng.Left
xlSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(image_file_name, False, True, rng.Left, rng.Top, height, width)
```

[AddPicture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198302.aspx) has an option to save the image with the document.

Height and Width are required. In the code above I am using the Range to size the image.